# Dynamically calling a static method in a JavaScript / ES7 class

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-2016, es6-class

I have the className in a string variable. I want to call the addField static method on the dynamic class.

```
const className = "CustomClient"; // comes from dropdown.
CustomClient.addField();
```

CustomClient is the name of the ES7 class. addField is static method. I want to call the addField dynamically. The class can be one of CustomClient, CustomContract or CustomUser.

Comment: do you need to create an instance of the class `CustomClient` ?

Comment: No, just call a static method on the class.

Comment: do you use modules? if so you probably need to import that class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's always the same when you want to reference a class by name - whether to instantiate it, to call a static method on it or something else: you have to build a name → class map and look it up:

```
const classes = {
    "CustomClient": CustomClient,
    …
}
var classRef = classes[className];
```

In your case, it would be

```
const classes = {CustomClient, CustomContract, CustomUser}; // shorthand notation
classes[className].addField();
```